# jQuery datepicker works in all browsers except IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have read related questions, but none of the solutions seems to work for me. I get an error when running my script.

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

Here is a snipit:

```
jQuery('#birthdate').datepicker({changeMonth: true,
                               changeYear: true,
                               yearRange: '1914:2013',
                   defaultDate: '-40y',
                   onSelect: function(selectedDate, inst) {
                               birthDay = selectedDate;
                                   getInputs();
                            }});
```

I have it in `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ...`
I also am linked to all of the relevant and new versions of jQuery, jQuery UI and CSS.

What displays is an input box that does nothing when I click on it.  It works great in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. Just not Internet Explorer, specifically IE9.

If it helps, the main page is here [link](http://gdl-leverage-calculator.site90.com/)
You can view the source to see the context of the snipit I provided. The code on that site uses code elsewhere and if you would find any of it useful, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have been toying with various versions just in case one in particular had issues with IE9, but all jquery and jquery ui versions I've been using seem to produce the same (undesireable) result.

Comment: Sorry. Internet Explorer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect from us.  You've described the problem but shown nothing that could possibly lead to a solution.  You need to post a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.  See http://sscce.org

Comment: Repost your second comment wrapped in \` particularly interested in the second one, but both is fine too.

Comment: Things I've tried so far is to use different versions of jQuery. I have also tried to include jQuery.noConflict(); I have also omitted other libraries I was wanting to include just in case. None of this work. Is that helpful?

Comment: You mean this? 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js'

Comment: No, the `<script>` tag. the \` symbol is the one left of the `1` key above tab.

Comment: Sorry, I am sort of new to this. `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Also note that I edited my post to contain the url where this site is located so you can see for yourselves. Perhaps looking at the source code of the page with the datepicker would be of use (?). I would like to help in any way I can to help you all help me.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the interested party, there were two things at play here. Most importantly, the server I was using was VERY slow. It was a free hosting site and I suppose I got what I paid for. Internet Explorer and, often, firefox were having trouble loading the page at all. Once I moved my files to a different server, things worked much better. Additionally, I had to choose, "Allow blocked content" in IE. Not sure what it was blocking, though. Perhaps the CDN connection to jQuery libraries??? Anyway, I would not recommend 000webhost unless you have no other option; and, if you do use them, expect the possibility of long delays in loading on at least some browsers.